# Dynamic positioning of popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic populated table from a database with a quite high count of of rows.
I've set up a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jGdm/79/)

In the driver row I have a pop up which will show me what drivers are currently available, and by clicking them i can assign a driver to the respective booking.

I want to pop up the driver-div directly under the row that has been clicked, as it is now the driver div pops up on a fixed location , and I need a way to dynamically update the position of the div to match the clicked row .

I have tried with `.position();` and `.index();` but i couldn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .offset()

```
$('#select-driver-list').offset( elem.offset() );
```

This will set the top of the driver box to the top of the link (elem). You can play with it to  add the height of the elem to the top of the box to have it show up

```
if (elem.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var o = elem.offset();
    o.top += elem.height();
    $('#select-driver-list').toggle(100).offset( o );
}
```

Comment: Where should i add the offset property exactly ? I'm new to jQuery and i've been trying to solve this problem for 8 hours and i still can't fix it .

Comment: You are a life saver my friend, i wish i could give you a beer.

Comment: Never acquired the taste for beer. Vodka is fine. ;-) Just remember to upvote the answer :-)

Comment: Can i ask you one more thing ? I've set a link for the driver like this 
`while($row_driver=mysqli_fetch_array($result_driver)){
    $driver = ucfirst($row_driver['username']);
    echo'<div class="driver-name">
          <a href="index.php?                                Booking='.urlencode($bookingid).'&Driver='.urlencode($row_driver['driver']">'.$driver.'</a>
       </div>';`

And now the request sends the booking id to the first id that is set in the table , how can i modify this so it will send the correct id for each booking ?

Comment: are you creating a driver list for each booking (table row)? or re-using a single driver list?

Comment: Im creating a driver list for each booking(table row) , i changed the ID of the "select-driver-list" into class , this solved my problem with the BookingID but when i click to add a driver all the divs pop up because they are a class now.

Comment: If the driver list is always the same, that is a huge waste of processing and bandwidth. Either way, you are going to a more complex solution.

Comment: And how do you recommend I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Updated logic only,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select-driver").each(function(e){
        $(this).on("click",function(){
            $(this).parent("div").siblings("div").toggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Working fine in : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dharam/3jGdm/93/)